# Can an element in xsd have an arbitrary name?

Tags: xml, xsd

I am new to xsd validation, and am trying to validate if a choice tag has a specific group of elements but also has ones with arbitrarily named. Something like the following:

```
...
<xs:choice>
  <xs:element name="test1" type="xs:string" />
  <xs:element name="test2" type="xs:string" />
  <xs:element name="-some regex or something to specify arbitrary name here" type="xs:string" />
</xs:choice>
...
```

Xml:

```
...
<test1>example text</test1>
<test2>example text again</test2>
<exampleNode>example text</exampleNode>
...
```

Is this possible in xsd? To validate against new arbitrarily named nodes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the xs:any wildcard to allow any element name, or any name within a particular set of namespaces. You can't restrict the name further (except by using assertions in XSD 1.1).

Using names with an internal structure (e.g. address-line-1, address-line-2, address-line-3) is invariably bad practice in XML design. In this case, a better design is `<address-line nr="1">` etc. So the idea of allowing names that match some regular expression suggests poor design. In general, XML Schema has been designed to make it difficult or impossible to write a schema for a poorly designed vocabulary.

Comment: This xml I'm working with is definitely poor design, I will give you that.

Comment: Can you somehow restrict the `any` element to match particular type, much like you can with named elements?

Answer (score 2):

Try this: `minOccurs="0"` makes it non-mandatory.

```
<xs:choice>
  <xs:element name="test1" type="xs:string" />
  <xs:element name="test2" type="xs:string" />
  <xs:any minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:choice>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be using entity references:
The schema:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema"> 
    <xsd:element name="Ferrari"/> 
    <xsd:element name="Lambo"/> 
    <xsd:element name="&supercar;"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

The XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE xsd:schema PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XML Schema 20000406//EN" "XMLSchema.dtd" [ <!ENTITY % p 'xsd:'> <!ENTITY % s ':xsd'>
<!ENTITY supercar 'McLaren'> 
]>
```

To change you dynamic name, when defining the schema in the XML document, just change supercar's name. 
I did not tested this, but it should give you the idea on how to achieve what you're trying to do.