# XML Schema for representing key-value pairs

Tags: xml, xsd, key-value

In my Java program I want to parse XML as a Map. To do this I want to create a schema that ensures that key names are unique and that there is no nesting. For example, this would be valid:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Data>
    <WaterLevel>4.1</WaterLevel>
    <Voltage>5</Voltage>
    <Pressure>30</Pressure>
</Data>
```

That is, there should not be deeper than 2 layers of nesting (i.e. one level below root only is permitted). Also, element names must be unique. There should not be 2 "WaterLevel" elements, for example. What XSD do I need to enforce this?

Comment: Please show the XML Schema you have so far, and explain in what way your current schema allows nesting. Thanks.

Comment: I don't have one yet because I am unsure how to make a schema that uses "unique" tag.

Comment: Does this "uniqueness" constraint imply that the element names in the XML document will be unpredictable?

Comment: Yes. The elements can be named anything but they have to be unique.

Comment: So, element names can be arbitrary and you accept any combination of them (as long as all are unique names), which would result in a very general schema indeed. Can you use XML Schema 1.1? Alternatively, why not write Java code to check this?

Comment: The only purpose of this schema is to ensure that key-value pairs can be parsed correctly in my code so I suppose it makes sense to do the check in the code but given the basic requirement I would've thought it'd be easy to create a schema to validate XML against before performing the mapping.

Comment: Which is indeed a good idea, but (I am tempted to say that) it cannot be done in XML Schema 1.0. Can you use XSD 1.1 (e.g. Xerces)?

Comment: As long as it's available in the standard Java library then yes. However given that it's difficult/impossible to do in XSD 1.0 I think I'll avoid it. I would be interested to know how it can be done in XSD 1.1 though, just to understand the challenge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would be interested to know how it can be done in XSD 1.1 though, just to understand the challenge.

Ensuring that arbitrary element names are unique is both a dynamic and document-wide constraint. It's dynamic because the element names cannot be defined in advance (as is ususally done in XSD documents).

In my opinion, your problem is not a good fit for XSD, but it can be done with XSD 1.1. There, you can use assertions that test XPath expressions. Here is an example:

**XML Schema 1.1**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:element name="Data">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <!--Allowing arbitrary element names-->
                <xs:any maxOccurs="unbounded" processContents="lax"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <!--Element names must be unique-->
            <xs:assert test="every $child in * satisfies not($child/preceding::*[name() = name($child)])"></xs:assert>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

The schema above would consider your document to be valid, but would reject a document like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Data>
    <WaterLevel>4.1</WaterLevel>
    <Voltage>5</Voltage>
    <Pressure>30</Pressure>
    <Voltage/>
</Data>
```

where the `Voltage` element occurs twice. But I have to emphasize that it is probably a bad idea and that you have not much control over the XML content of instance documents - while being in control is the whole point of XML validation.

See [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9632992/1987598) for more explanations about the feasibility of arbitrary element names. The gist of Michael Kay's answer there is: an XML design where element names are arbitrary is designed badly.

Comment: Thanks for the help :)